# Bootsrap fixed navbar doesnt have margin bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I creatad a simple theme with bootstrap 4. The navbar has a fixed-top class. Under the nav, i have this div, that has the page title as content.

```
<div class="aloldal_text_div">
<div class="container">
    <h1><?php get_site_cim($siteID); ?></h1>
</div>
```

My problem is, that this div "goes up" to the navbar. I give it some margin-top, but its not okay, i think because the fixed navbar.

[image]

Can someone help me fix this? [You can see my site on this link](https://vizszigetelesem.hu/szolgaltatasok).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give `margin-top` for `.aloldal_text_div` your header height

```
.aloldal_text_div{
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px 0;
   background:#d3bf84;
   color:#fff;
   margin: 67px 0 0; /*edit here*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you! When i use fixed top navbar, i should do this always with margin?